# How to extract background-image URL from div style selenium/python?

Tags: python, css, selenium

```
<div style="left: 0%;background-image: url(&quot;https://i.xxxx.com/pictures/3724063802.jpg?type=original&quot;);width: 100%;height: 100%;background-size: contain;background-position: 50% 50%;background-repeat: no-repeat;position: absolute;"></div>
```

How do I locate and extract the background-image URL from the above html in selenium using Python?
My problem is that I've earlier used the id, how do I do it without an id?

Comment: Use a css_selector. Right click the element and inspect and copy the selector. Then parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using an XPath to find the div (`find_element_by_xpath("//div")`) and you these can be indexed to find the specific div element you're looking for (`//div[3]`, `//div[0]`, etc.)

To extract background-image, use the `value_of_css_property()` method.

```
bg_url = div.value_of_css_property('background-image') # 'url("https://i.xxxx.com/img.jpg")'
# strip the string to leave just the URL part
bg_url = bg_url.lstrip('url("').rstrip('")')
# https://i.xxxx.com/img.jpg
```

Another way is doing `find_elements_by_tag_name('div')` as this will return a list of divs, but you'd have to sift through them to find the one you want.

Comment: Thank you! Just copied the Xpath: div = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id='abc-asd']/div[2]/div[2]...) then took the value of css property: bg_url = div.value_of_css_property('background-image') and stripped it! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Anytime! Glad I could help :)